# Best way to show a document field in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

If I have a collection with this kind of documents:

```
{
    "Category" : "DVDs",
    "items" : {
        "Name" : "Mission Impossible",
        "Owner" : "me",
        "LentTo" : "Alice"
    },
    "_id" : "4ocjZXCbLk5Zo8afp"
}
```

What's the easiest way to show "DVDs" in the browser.

I could do it by adding `{{list_cat}}` in a template or by creating this function:

```
Template.list.list_cat = function () {
  if (Session.equals('current_list', null)) return null;
  else {
    var cats = lists.findOne({ _id: Session.get('current_list')});
    return cats.Category;
  }
}
```

But I'm sure there is a faster cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't `items` be an array, not just a single object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a template in which you show a list of documents, you can just refer directly to the property:

```
<body>
  {{> documents}}
  <br/><br/>
  {{> selected_doc}}
</body>

<template name="documents">
  {{#each document}}
  <div>{{Category}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="selected_doc">
  Selected doc:<br/>
  Name: {{items.Name}}<br/>
  Owner: {{items.Owner}}<br/>
  Lent to: {{items.LentTo}}
</template>

Template.documents.events({
  "click div": function() {
    Session.set("selected_doc", this._id);
  }
});

Template.selected_doc = function() {
  return lists.findOne({_id: Session.get("selected_doc")});
}
```

Comment: Hello Rahul, I could go so far but what I'm trying to do is clicking one category and the show the details of the document having this category. My idea is to put this document in a session object and then access it from a template using this object but I didn't succeed in doing it. All the examples are with collections, never with a single document. Thx!

Comment: I updated the answer to include clicking a category, storing it in a session and then displaying the selected document.